# Can I capture the text-to-speech output of google talkback as text?

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, talkback

I am trying to automate some tests to confirm that talkback is spitting out the correct information in regards to any buttons and links in an android app.  I am doing this in intelliJ in Java and the automation code is entirely separate from the app, so it isn't an android project and I don't believe I can make use the android SDK because of that.  Is there a way using appium, selenium, and java for me to capture the text output that talkback would read off from an emulator so I can compare that to the actual text or content of various elements?  If this isn't possible, does anyone know how google talkback generates the text that the speech engine reads off of?